# Flatness criterion for $I$-adic ring: $I$-torsion free

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, flatness, valuation-rings

Let $R$ be an $I$-adically separated and complete valuation ring, with $I$ finitely generated.

It is used a few times in Bosch, [Lectures on Formal and Rigid Geometry](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Etongliu/seminar/rigid/Bosch.pdf) e.g. first lines of pg. 164, Cor. 5 and Cor. 6 (their condition (V) is what I stated above) that

> If an $A$ module has no $I$ torsion then it is flat over $R$.

I don't see why this is true. Any suggestions / references would be appreciated.

---

What I thought: We know $A$ is flat over domain $R$ iff it is $R$-torsion free.

If the statement were true:  $I$-torsion free $\Rightarrow$$R$-torsion free.

This would hold if  $I$ is a maximal ideal but otherwise I don't see why.

Comment: What book by Bosch? Anyway, maybe the answer is here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51095/flat-module-and-torsion-free-module?rq=1

Comment: Sorry,  I added it, didn't know why the hyper link didn't show up. and unfortunately I can't find which part of the llink addresses this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Section 7.3 it is assumed that $I$ is the ideal of definition or $R$. It follows that the $I$-adic topology is separated, so (because $R$ is a valuation ring) every nonzero ideal of $R$ contains some power of $I$, so everything that is $R$-torsion is $I$-torsion.

Comment: Now looking back: is having no $I$-torsion the same as being flat when $R$ is of type (N) in the text? (N)=Noetherian adic with ideal of defitiion $I$. (page 162). In otherwords is iii of definition 3 equivalent to being flat?